# Plancherel measure on Homogeneous spaces. 

Tags: fourier-analysis, rt.representation-theory

Does any one know what the correct formulation of the plancherel theorem should be for Homogeneous spaces. More specific I am looking for a statement like: there is a unique measure in $\mu$ in $\hat G $ such that $L^2(G/H)=\int_{\hat G}^{\oplus}H(\xi)d\mu(\xi)$ and something like a functional $I(f)=\int_{\hat G}^{\oplus}Tr(\xi(f))d\mu $ I will appreciate a lot your help. I am more familiar with the language of C^* algebras so if you can state this in that setting will be even better.

Comment: What restrictions are you typically imposing on G and H? It isn't clear to me what such a formula would mean if G were the free group on two generators and H were the identity; but that could just be my ignorance.

Comment: G is a reductive algebraic group over a local field. And H is a closed subgroup. From this you can conclude that G is a postliminal separable group. And there is hope for a plancherel measure. In the case you stated the free group in two generators is not separable so I am not sure we can say something there.    

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. "The free group in two generators is not separable" - in what sense do you mean "separable"?

Comment: It does not have a dense countable subset. 

Comment: Carlos, have you seen the book "Lie Theory: Harmonic Analysis on Symmetric Spaces--General Plancherel Theorems"? A version of van den Ban's contribution is available on his website (under Lecture Notes). He also has a survey in PSPM 61 ("Harmonic Analysis on semisimple symmetric spaces. A survey of some general results.") which is available from his website (under Publications).

Comment: No I have not seen it. But I will take a look at it thank you very much BR.

Answer (score 2):

May be the paper:  "MR0444844 (56 #3191) Penney, Richard Abstract Plancherel theorems and a Frobenius reciprocity theorem. J. Functional Analysis 18 (1975), 177–190"  is what you are looking for.